# Equivalence of norms in a Banach Space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces

I am trying to prove the following

> Let $X$ be a Banach space in two norms $\| \cdot \|_1$ and $\| \cdot \|_2$, and suppose that $\| \cdot \|_1 \leq C \| \cdot \|_2$ for some $C>0$. Show that the two norms are equivalent.

I tried to play with the defition of equivalent norms ($D\|\cdot \|_1 \leq \|\cdot\|_2 \leq C\|\cdot\|_1$ and $F\|\cdot \|_2 \leq \|\cdot\|_1 \leq E\|\cdot\|_2$) but I didn't get anywhere. Also, I can't use the open mapping theorem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What tools are you allowed to use? This statement trivially follows from the open mapping theorem, without this theorem I believe it might get complicated.

Comment: I have a characterization of a Banach space (X is Banach space if every absolutely convergent sequence is convergent), some results on linear operators (continuous iff bounded, the vector space of linear bounded operators is a Banach space) and Hahn-Banach.

Answer (score 1):

We want to show that there exists $D$ such that $\|x\|_2 \leq D\|x\|_1$. Suppose that for every integer $n$, there exists $x_n$ with $\|x_n\|_1=1$ and $\|x_n\|_2>n$, we deduce that ${{x_n}\over n}$ converges towards $0$ in $(X,\|,\|_1)$ since $Id:(X,\|,\|_1)\rightarrow (X,\|,\|_2)$ is continuous ${{x_n}\over n}$ converges towards $0$ in $(X,\|,\|_2)$ contradiction since $\|{{x_n}\over n}\|_2>1$.

Comment: How do you know the identity map is continuous? Isn't this what you actually want to prove? By assumption convergence in $||,||_2$ implies convergence in $||,||_1$, not the other way around.

Comment: If I understand correctly, $\|\cdot\|_1 \leq C \|\cdot\|_2$ implies that $Id: (X, \|\cdot\|_1) \rightarrow (X,\|\cdot\|_2)$ is bounded, and thus we know that it is continuous.

Comment: @mat95 But bounded means that $||Id(x)||_2\leq D||x||_1$ for some $D>0$. This is not what is given. What we know is that $Id: (X, ||\cdot||_2)\to (X, ||\cdot||_1)$ is bounded. I think the answer is wrong. After all, I don't see where the assumption that we work in Banach spaces was used. The statement is clearly false in non complete spaces.

Comment: Right, right. I got confused.